# simulator for PayPal NVP API - NameValuePairs

Tags: spring-boot, paypal

I have an app which interacts with the PayPal NVP API. I am developing a simulator app to simulate the responses as they are coming from PayPal NVP API.

The calling app is initiating the PayPal NVP as:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = paypalRestTemplate.postForEntity(paypalEndpoint, request, String.class);
```

This `response` object is sent parsed to get the NVP elements as:

```
List<NameValuePair> responseDataList = URLEncodedUtils.parse(responseContent, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Simulator Code:
In the simulator code, I have a Controller class with this signature:

```
@PostMapping (consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> transactions(
            @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> paypalRequest) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        return payPalService.processRequest(paypalRequest, delay);
    }
```

Simulator Service class:
In the Simulator Service class, I am creating a NaveValuePair object as this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Adding the different fields as:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ACK",SUCCESS));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1","value1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2","value2"));
...
...
```

and returning the `namevaluepairs` as:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(nameValuePairs.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Back in the PayPal service class I see that the `responseDataList` above is returning as NameValuePairs as `ACK=Success,name1=value1,name3=value3` with ACK as the name and the rest of the stuff as a single value
instead of individual name/values as:
`ACK=Success,`
`name1=value1,`
`name2=value2....`

How can I get a name/value pairs returned in this scenario?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing code to use the 20-year-old NVP API? It's essentially deprecated and in maintenance mode, anything current should be done using v2/checkout/orders or similar REST APIs. For checkout, see the backend samples at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ and pair it with the JS SDK for approval

Comment: We have started moving away from NVP but in the meantime we still need this NVP and for some testing we need to get this simulator which simulates the PayPal NVP responses

Comment: There are ways to generate negative errors from the API itself https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/error-conditions/ -- anyway, of course simulating them yourself is also doable, this is a Java question so I'll leave it for someone else to answer. Try asking ChatGPT as well, it's pretty good at generating code for such straightforward things

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by formatting the returned namevaluepair. The actual service is expecting "&" as the delimitter. This is what is being returned from the actual PayPal NVP response.

```
for (NameValuePair nameValPair: nameValuePairs) {
            buffer.append(nameValPair.toString()).append("&");
        }
```

Once I add that for each namevaluepair, it worked fine.
As suggested above its a Java problem rather than Apache NameValuePair.